# Sync SQLite data with FireBase automatically

Tags: sqlite, firebase

Actually my data is in `GB` so every time manually sync for updating is not make sense. So I want to sync my SQLite database with Firebase database automatically, either it may be offline or online. And I want syncing from both ways. "FB to SQLite" and "SQLite to FB".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually firebase use persistency to work while offline but dynamically can get only last event whatever it is. So have to write our own Sync for that.

Answer (score 0):

Is it in Android ? if you already have functionality to manual sync the data, then should not be a problem to automate it. You can call same sync functionality through a service, which in turn will use CountDownTimer. CountDownTimer as per preference can be called every couple of minutes or hourly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality for Firebase to synchronize with SQlite, nor built-in functionality in SQlite to synchronize with Firebase.

But since both have an API, you can write code to do the synchronization for you.